# Updating a MySQL table every couple of seconds with large amounts of data?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session

I've create an application that has an autosave feature. So instead of the user having to click a save button, their settings are automatically saved with every interaction with app. Behind the scenes, every time the app changes, I POST the data to PHP and update a MySQL database table.

It's working well but nobody's using it yet so my question is: If I'm updating a MySQL database table with this save data (and the saved data could be the equivalent of a 100kb XML file) every couple of seconds, could I experience performance issues? It should be noted that there could be hundreds or thousands of users using the app at the same time.

Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Think of a better way to do this, i.e. only send changed or new data

Comment: I am only sending changed data but the nature of the app means things are changing constantly

Comment: @kevin - it's more of a preventative measure in case the users browser window closes than an autosave.

Comment: How fast can your average user type? I can't imagine it being so much.

Comment: @Andrew Right, but what if the close was because they decided that instead of submitting the data, they want to cancel?

Comment: @AmazingDreams: It's a website building tool so the users are dragging items around the screen. As such, they are constantly changing the state of the app.

Comment: Then you send the changed stuff... nothing more... and only in batch.. It is not like the size of the box is linearly equivalent to the size of the data needed to remember that. That's just a couple of bytes right there.

Comment: @Kevin - they can then re-open the page. It doesn't save over the page, it's only meant for if they refresh the page.

Comment: I'd suggest at least batching interactions rather than saving on every interaction, similar to how an email client saves drafts of your email periodically rather than on every keystroke.

Comment: @Kevin - yes, that's a good suggestion - I'm going to use a timer and serialize as per XaxD's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Bundle up and serialize all your data changes into a single JSON object before POSTING (as a single field). Fewer large interactions will offer better performances than constant tiny ones.

Comment: Thanks XaxD - that's a good suggestion.